# pysftp.Connection.get IOError: b35d5d74-ecb1-4a41-a9ed-5dde9b15960d

Tags: python, pysftp

Currently receiving an IOError: b35d5d74-ecb1-4a41-a9ed-5dde9b15960d when using sftp.Connection.get()

I have the following code

```py
SFTP = pysftp.Connection(
    "xxx",
    username='xxx',
    password='xxx'
)
filename = "foo"
if SFTP.exists('data/{}'.format(filename)):
    SFTP.get('data/{}'.format(filename))
```

It passes the "if SFTP.exists('data/{}'.format(filename)):" line (and entering it in the console debugging returns True) so the file exists.

The full error message is:

```py
File "C:\WinPython-32bit-2.7.6.3-20140407\python-2.7.6\lib\site-packages\pysftp.py", line 233, in get
    self._sftp.get(remotepath, localpath, callback=callback)
File "C:\WinPython-32bit-2.7.6.3-20140407\python-2.7.6\lib\site-packages\paramiko\sftp_client.py", line 640, in get
    size = self.getfo(remotepath, fl, callback)
File "C:\WinPython-32bit-2.7.6.3-20140407\python-2.7.6\lib\site-packages\paramiko\sftp_client.py", line 610, in getfo
    fr.prefetch()
File "C:\WinPython-32bit-2.7.6.3-20140407\python-2.7.6\lib\site-packages\paramiko\sftp_file.py", line 396, in prefetch
    size = self.stat().st_size
File "C:\WinPython-32bit-2.7.6.3-20140407\python-2.7.6\lib\site-packages\paramiko\sftp_file.py", line 239, in stat
    t, msg = self.sftp._request(CMD_FSTAT, self.handle)
File "C:\WinPython-32bit-2.7.6.3-20140407\python-2.7.6\lib\site-packages\paramiko\sftp_client.py", line 649, in _request
    return self._read_response(num)
File "C:\WinPython-32bit-2.7.6.3-20140407\python-2.7.6\lib\site-packages\paramiko\sftp_client.py", line 696, in _read_response
    self._convert_status(msg)
File "C:\WinPython-32bit-2.7.6.3-20140407\python-2.7.6\lib\site-packages\paramiko\sftp_client.py", line 726, in _convert_status
    raise IOError(text)
IOError: b35d5d74-ecb1-4a41-a9ed-5dde9b15960d
```

Comment: You are missing the local file path in your SFTP.get call.

Comment: Local file path is not required. If you look at the documentation, if no local file path is included, the file gets copied into the current working repository.